# Mysql Workbench connection ssl not enable

Tags: mysql, ssl, connection, workbench

I'm trying to connect local database using mysql workbench but i can't connect.i tried test connection.it warned pop up window write **"ssl not enable"**.
how can i connect my local database

this is screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 38):

This is just a info popup, telling you, that SSL is not enabled. Just installed Workbench and stubmled over the same message, thinking that indicates a problem :D
Yes, you can of course connect to your DB.

Comment: LOL. Same here. I kept on clicking test connection thinking its an error. Works well =)

Comment: When you let the DB guys do UX ;)